# newbie capistrano rails deployment problem (can't find git in the path)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, capistrano

I'm using: Rails 3, ruby 1.9.2 and trying to deploy using capistrano.  **When I run cap deploy:check, capistrano tells me that it can't find git on my deployment server (see below).**

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong??

Here's my setup.

- I have a git repo @ github
- I have a
  laptop with an updated local copy of
  the github repo
- I have a local
  "production" server (192.168.0.103) where the
  production app should be deployed
- I'm running all commands from the local repo on my laptop (not the production server)

If I run `cap deploy:setup`, my deploy.rb file successfully adds the "releases" and "shared" directories on my production server (aka 192.168.0.103).

If I run the cap deploy:check command, it fails with the error message of 
**`git' could not be found in the path (192.168.0.103).**

What is strange (to me at least) is that git is definitely installed on 192.168.0.103 and the command that's used to see if git is there (which git) works when I ssh into 192.168.0.103.

So, obviously I'm doing something wrong (maybe in the deploy.rb file?)

Here's a sanitized version of the deploy.rb file

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :application, "myapp"
set :repository,  "git@github.com:xxxxxxx/myapp.git"
set :user, "abcde" #username that's used to ssh into 192.168.0.103
set :scm, :git
set :scm_passphrase, "xxxxxxxx" 
set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :deploy_to, "/Users/abcde/www"

role :web, "192.168.0.103"
role :app, "192.168.0.103"
```

Here's the output of cap deploy:check

```
  * executing `deploy:check'
  * executing "test -d /Users/abcde/www/releases"
    servers: ["192.168.0.103"]
Password: 
    [192.168.0.103] executing command
    command finished
  * executing "test -w /Users/abcde/www"
    servers: ["192.168.0.103"]
    [192.168.0.103] executing command
    command finished
  * executing "test -w /Users/abcde/www/releases"
    servers: ["192.168.0.103"]
    [192.168.0.103] executing command
    command finished
  * executing "which git"
    servers: ["192.168.0.103"]
    [192.168.0.103] executing command
    command finished
The following dependencies failed. Please check them and try again:
--> `git' could not be found in the path (192.168.0.103)
```

Comment: It appears that git is not in the path for the user that the server deploys with. Which user do you ssh into the server as and which user does the server deploy with? Am I making sense? I have limited server knowledge but this seems like the issue to me. Also, this would fair better on serverfault.com.

Comment: AndrewKs, Thanks for this.  I didn't realized serverfault.com existed, but I'll post any future issues.  Turns out that it wasn't a user/path/permissions issue (see my "self-answer" below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured it out.

I was basically having the same problem as described here: http://groups.google.com/group/capistrano/browse_thread/thread/50af1daed0b7a393

Here's a choice excerpt:

> I try to deploy an application on a
>   shared environment on which I 
>   installed git. I have added the path
>   to bashrc, **but this would work  only
>   in an interactive bash. When cap is
>   logging in, it will not be  running
>   bash**.  If I run deploy:check it fails
>   by 
>   --> `git' could not be found in the path (example.com)  If i set
>   :scm_command, "/home/user/opt/bin/git"
>   the problem is solved  with the
>   deploy:check command, but when I run
>   deploy:cold, it fails  because it
>   tries to run /home/user/opt/bin/git
>   locally and I can't  even put git in
>   there, because I use windows on my pc.

adding :scm_command, "path/to/my/git" fixed the issue, although I'm not 100% that this is the correct approach to take.

Comment: @user141146- I had the same problem. The :scm_command is not working for capistrano 3.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using:

```
default_run_options[:env] = {'PATH' => '/home/user/opt/bin/git:$PATH'}
```

This will allow adjusting the PATH system environment variable (and of them more if needed) so that not only the "Capistrano can't find the SCM" problem get solved bu any other similar problems with Capistrano not running in interactive bash (not executing the .bashrc etc.).